# Assigning IB textfields to delegate UITextField properties

Tags: iphone, objective-c, delegates, interface-builder, uitextfield

I have three textfields in interface builder being used to accept input. When a button is pushed the data in the 3 fields are processed. Currently, when one of the textfields sends out a textFieldShouldReturn (or similar) message to its delegate, I assign the "sender" parameter (using the tag property) to the delegate's respective UITextField instance variable.

I run into a problem if the button is pushed, but the user has taken no action inside the textfield, essentially leaving the delegate's UITextFields as nil. A simple work around is to just check for nil and assume that nil means an empty textfield, but I'm sure there is a more appropriate pattern within this context to achieve the same goal.

Essentially, how do I assign IB textfields to the delegate UITextField properties without the user taking some action to invoke the delegate?

Answer (score 0):

If your delegate object is represented in the xib file (it's the owner or something), you could use IBOutlets to connect the textfields to delegate variables. See the [Interface Builder User Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/IB_UserGuide/CodeIntegration/CodeIntegration.html).

If your delegate is not there, there's probably a place in your code that assigns the delegate to the textfield and hence know both of them. You could set the textfield on the delegate at the same time.